# Fail to locate a web element which exists in DOM

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test.
I used:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
(By.xpath("//input[@name='contactInformation.contact_name']")));
```

to locate a Webelement and when I check the DOM we have:

```
<input type="text" class="assetContactInformationContactName" 
name="contactInformation.contact_name" value=""
     id="jsonform-9754-elt-contactInformation.contact_name" 
required="required" placeholder="Name">
```

But it fails saying that:

```
    Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for visibility of 
element located by By.xpath: //input[@name='ContactInformation.contact_name']
```

Comment: you have 2 different xpaths. the first one is correct, the second one has wrong name (the check is case-sensitive). 

So if you don't know exactly how it is typed you can try lower-case(@name) = lower-case('ContactInformation.contact_name').

Comment: @Luciddream thanks indeed, please post it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different xpaths. the first one is correct, the second one has wrong name (the check is case-sensitive). So if you don't know exactly how it is typed you can try

```
//input[lower-case(@name) = lower-case('ContactInformation.contact_name')]
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.name("contactInformation.contact_name")); - use this
Let me know if it helps.